# Changing Django session engine without destroying existing sessions

Tags: django

I'm currently running a Django application with `SESSION_ENGINE` configured as `django.contrib.sessions.backends.db`. I'd like to change this to `django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db` for a performance boost.

Can I make this change without destroying the existing sessions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can make this change without logged in users suddenly finding themselves being logged out. That's because [cached_db](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cached_db.py#L39) checks memcache first for the key and if it cannot be found in it, goes to the database. Thus making this change will not cause a loss of session data. Fragment of code from cached_db

```
def load(self):
    try:
        data = self._cache.get(self.cache_key)
    except Exception:
        # Some backends (e.g. memcache) raise an exception on invalid
        # cache keys. If this happens, reset the session. See #17810.
        data = None

    if data is None:
        # Duplicate DBStore.load, because we need to keep track
        # of the expiry date to set it properly in the cache.
```

However please note that cached sessions backends are a bit over rated. Depending on the middleware that you have, the session object may be updated very often, as often as every request if only to change the expire date. In that case you will find that the database is being written to all the time. Which means the cached value has to be discarded too.

Comment: In comparison, how's your experience been with using pure cache backends (no db)?

Comment: I've never used a pure cache session backend in production. If you want to use one, I would recommend a redis based system rather than a memcached based system. However all this takes a lot of effort and at best it will only save you a few milliseconds per request.

Comment: Well I've been playing around with redis since you first intro'd me to it, so I feel pretty comfortable with it. But if indeed the perf boost is small, I could avoid using it. Also re: pure cache backends, I've read that because it disregards persistence, session data is expunged from time to time. I don't quite want that.

Comment: actually it's not expunged from time to time. What happens is that if the cache get's filled, someone gets removed every time a new item is inserted. That may not be a bad thing because you don't want users to be logged in for ever. Even gmail etc also ask you to login from time to time.

Comment: I see, I mistook the language in Django docs which mentioned it getting expunged from time to time (sic).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to. **cached_db** backend is just a write-through cache to a database backed, persistent, **db** backend which speeds up your read queries. It will not speed up your write queries, so you should try and find out how much you are reading and writing the session data.

Your [Django SECRET_KEY](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#std:setting-SECRET_KEY) setting determines your session key hashing parametrs along with [Session settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#sessions) that determine the cache you will use for sessions and session your TTLs, so if you are not changing those variables, you should be good.